# C++. Не правильно использую GetUserName() и GetDiskFreeSpace() в WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Следующий фрагмент кода, использующий GetUserNameA():

```
std::string getUserName()
{
    DWORD nameLength   = 64;
    LPSTR computerName = new CHAR[nameLength];
    GetUserNameA(computerName, &nameLength);

    std::string name(computerName);
    delete[] computerName;

    return name;
}
```

работает должным образом под MinGW, но не под MSVC. Вот ошибка линковки, которую он выдаёт:

windowsoptions.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp_GetUserNameA в функции "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl WindowsOptions::getUserName(void)" (?getUserName@WindowsOptions@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)

А этот код использует GetDiskFreeSpaceA():

```
int64_t WindowsOptions::getDriveTotalSize(const std::string &driveName)
{
    DWORD totalClusters;
    DWORD freeClusters;
    DWORD sectorsPerCluster;
    DWORD bytesPerSector;
    GetDiskFreeSpaceA(driveName.c_str(),
                      &sectorsPerCluster,
                      &bytesPerSector,
                      &freeClusters,
                      &totalClusters);

    int64_t totalBytes = totalClusters * sectorsPerCluster * bytesPerSector;

    return totalBytes;
}
```

и даёт неправильный результат под одну из версий MinGW (под другую всё хорошо) и MSVC.

Последняя функция, как видно, перемножает возвращаемые значения и вычисляет общее число байт на диске. При дебаге удалось выяснить следующее:

---

totalClusters = 121804599

sectorsPerCluster = 8

bytesPerSector = 512

totalClusters * sectorsPerCluster = 974436792

totalClusters * sectorsPerCluster * bytesPerSector = 695431168 (неверно!)

---

Как будто переполнение, хотя 64 бита вполне хватает для хранения значения ёмкости любого накопителя.

Если бы я знал тему глубже... Приходится просить помощи.

Comment: Возможно ошибаюсь, но мне казалось, что размер DWORD 32 бита? Или нет? Посмотрите, как определен этот тип в разных версия MinGW и MSVC

Comment: А вообще заголовки типа "_неправильно работает системная функция ХХХ_" стоило бы автозаменой исправлять на "_я не умею правильно использовать системную функцию ХХХ_".

Comment: Стоило бы, в следующий раз буду следить за собой. Но не смотря на это смысл всё равно один и тот же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат перемножения DWORD (uint32_t) это DWORD. Оно переполнятся и только потом вы кладете его в int64_t.

Перемножайте int64_t:

```
auto totalBytes = int64_t(totalClusters) * sectorsPerCluster * bytesPerSector;
```